# Why IEnumerator.MoveNext is called before GetCurrent?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, il

I am completely new to IL, but as I know `MoveNext` should be called before `Current`, lets say we have such foreach statement:

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Empty<string>())
{          
}
```

if we look at generated IL we will see that Current is actually called first:

```
IL_0014:  br.s       IL_001f
IL_0016:  ldloc.1
IL_0017:  callvirt   instance !0 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<string>::get_Current()
IL_001c:  stloc.0
IL_001d:  nop
IL_001e:  nop
IL_001f:  ldloc.1
IL_0020:  callvirt   instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
IL_0025:  stloc.2
IL_0026:  ldloc.2
IL_0027:  brtrue.s   IL_0016
IL_0029:  leave.s    IL_003b
```

The question is why?

Comment: Current will not be called first, at IL_0014 is an unconditional branch to IL_001f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IL_0014:  br.s       IL_001f
```

According to MSDN, [`br.s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.br_s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Unconditionally transfers control to a target instruction (short form).

The referenced address is the instructions which call `MoveNext`.

```
IL_001f:  ldloc.1
IL_0020:  callvirt   instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
```

Comment: Why do they need this unconditional transfer? Doesn't it make more sense to write it sequentially?

Comment: @AndriusCepaitis It is not written by human, it is generated automatically by the compiler. I don't think *more sense* is its priority